# Auto scaling and data replication on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Here is my scenario.

We have an ELB setup with two reserved instances of EC2 acting as web server under it (Amazon Linux).

There are some rapidly changing files (pdf, xls, jpg, etc) on the web server which are consumed by the websites hosted on the EC2 instances. Code files are identical and we will be sure to update both the servers manually at the same time with new code as and when needed.

The main problem is the user uploaded content which is stored on the EC2 instance. 
What is the best approach to make sure that the uploaded files are available on both the servers almost instantly ?

Many people have suggested the use of rsync or unison, but this will involve setting a cron job. I am looking for something like FileSystemWatcher in C# which is triggered 
 ONLY when the contents of the specified folder are changed. Moreover due to the ELB we are not sure which of the EC2 instances will actually be connected to the user when the files are uploaded.

To add to the above we have one more Staging Server which pushes certain files to one of the EC2 web servers. We want these files too replicated to the other instance.

I was wondering whether S3 can solve the problem ? Will this setup be still good if we decide to enable auto scaling ?
I am confused at this stage. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

S3 will be the choice for your case. In this way, you don't have to sync files between EC2 instances. Also it is probably the best choice if you need to enable auto scaling. You should not put any data in EC2 instances, they should be stateless so that you can easily auto scale.

To use S3, it will require your application to support it instead of directly writing to local file system. It should be quite easy, there are many libraries in each language which can help you to store files into S3.

Comment: that looks to be an expensive proposition for large files...this might also lead to one more complication.
we save apache access/error logs on the EC2. These will be different for both the instances. We are required by LAW to maintain the logs for 3 months. How is this handled with auto scaling ?

Comment: @Amol,  you can use a centralized log management, like splunk, logstash, loggly etc to manage your logs.